# Show method from module in cms static block

Tags: magento-1.9, plugin

I have **plugin** who method **show text**. I would like call the function from my block in cms static block. How to do this? Any hints?

Comment: provide some code and example what you are trying

Answer (score 0):

You have to call any block file from static block like :

```
{{block type="core/template" template="custom/custom.phtml"}}
```

and in this file you can call that plugin method and echo that value.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to display your block in phtml to test if your block works fine like this:

```
<?php echo Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('yourfolder/yourfile.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

If your Block work correctly you should call it in your cmc page like this

```
{{block type="core/template" name="your.block.name" template="yourfolder/yourfile.phtml"}}
```